# What happens to the time it takes for my noodles to cook, and the temperature of the boiling water?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a boiling pot of water that I am going to cook my Sponge Bob Noodles in.   I am very hungry and want the noodles to cook faster, so I turn up the heat from medium to high.( Note, the water was already boiling at medium).What happens to the time it takes for my noodles to cook, and the temperature of the boiling water?

Answer (score 3):

When you put in the noodles the temperature of the water will fall below the boiling point for a time interval delta(t) until it reaches boiling point again, i.e. the noodles go from room temperature to boiling point.

This interval becomes smaller the higher the energy provided during the transition period. So if you are in a hurry, provide high heat. You might gain a minute or three, depending on the heat source and pot and volume of water and noodles.

If you are energy conscious turn down the heat after it boils again.

Comment: To emphasize, once the water returns to a boil, any heat beyond the minimum needed to keep it boiling is completely wasted.